# Consequences of overriding the global new/delete operators

Tags: c++, new-operator, delete-operator

I'm interested in the consequences of overriding the global new/delete operators. Let's suppose:

1. The code overrides those operators to use a custom generic-purpose allocator.
2. The code also uses an external library.

If the external library allocates a chunk of memory, what new-operator will it use? Let's suppose the library returns that pointer asking the user to delete it (after he has done with it), if the library is using the "vanilla" new-operator how can the user delete that memory (since his version of the delete-operator is quite different)?

What if the code is compiled to create a library and then distributed, how those global new/delete operators will effect the codes of the users?

Are there any other critical consequences to look for in these scenarios?

Comment: The replaced operator is *linked* in at the end; how your code is partitioned into libraries doesn't matter.

Comment: When you have true libraries, I agree with you. But DLL on Windows are special animals (closer to a true executable than to a true library). So corner cases could occur if a DLL statically links a version of operator new/delete and the main exec (or another DLL) also statically links another version.